# Joomla problemas para instalar nuevo componente

Tags: linux, ubuntu, joomla3, virtualbox

Buen dia. estoy intentando crear un proyecto en joomla es el projectfork al momento de instalar el paquete desde el administrador me aparece este error ya cambie permisos y sigue apareciendo alguna idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Ocurre con cualquier extensión?

Comment: Hasta el momento solo he probado con projectfork. alguna idea del porque agradezco mucho tu apoyo Shaz.

Comment: Por favor intenta primero con otras extensiones, más genericas o conocidas en la comunidad, o con una plantilla.

Comment: es un problema de permisos, cambia el owner y los permisos de carpetas y archivos